# How to Left Justify part of a String in python?

Tags: python, string, formatting, justify

I want to left justify the right part of a string. I am writing an IRC Bot's HELP command and I want the description to be left justified at the same width throughout:

```
List of commands:
## !          Say a Text
## execute    Execute an IRC command
## help       Help for commands
```

**ljust** works for a whole string, but how do I do this on a part of a string only?

This is my current code for generating the string:

```
format.color( "## ", format.LIME_GREEN ) + self.commands[ cmd ][1].__doc__.format( format.bold( cmd ) ).splitlines()[0].strip()
```

Comment: Split the strings in the relevant parts, ljust the ones you want, and join the pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/library/string.html#formatspec) and [printf-style String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

**EXAMPLE:**

```
>>> '{:<20} {}'.format('## execute', 'Execute an IRC command')
'## execute           Execute an IRC command'
```

Note that `format()` was introduced in Python 3.0 and backported to Python 2.6, so if you are using an older version, the same result can be achieved by:

```
>>> '%-20s %s' % ('## execute', 'Execute an IRC command')
'## execute           Execute an IRC command'
```

It's necessary to split the strings in a sensible manner beforehand.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
>>> '{:<20} {}'.format(*'{0} <COMMAND>: Help for <command>'.split(': '))
'{0} <COMMAND>        Help for <command>'

>>> '%-20s %s' % tuple('{0} <COMMAND>: Help for <command>'.split(': '))
'{0} <COMMAND>        Help for <command>
```

Comment: this works for that list, but how do I go around formatting this:
    "{0} <COMMAND>: Help for <command>"

Comment: okay, your second one works that perfect that I switched to yours for compactibility. I didn't now the .format() engine was this powerfull!

Answer (score 0):

You rightly mention [`str.ljust`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust), so it's just a case of splitting your string as appropriate and applying it to the 'left' part. E.g:

```
>>> parts = "## ! Say a Text".split(" ", 2)
>>> " ".join(parts[:2]).ljust(20)+parts[2]
'## !                Say a Text'
```

Obviously, it may be better to do this before you start joining the string for simplicity.